# Mapping a range of positive integers to range of inidices

Tags: java, math, mapping

Basically, what I need is some kind of a mapping function that should map an integer (0 - N) to an index (0 - M). For N = 10, M = 3, the function should map: 
*1 -> **0**, 2 -> **1**, 3 -> **2**, 4 -> **3**, 5 -> **0**, 6 -> **1**, 7 -> **2**, 8 -> **3**, 9 -> **0** and 10 -> **1**.*

My brain is pretty dead so I ended up with some bull*&^% mapping :)

```
public int getIndexForNumber(int number, int maxIndex) {
    int max = maxIndex;
    while (maxIndex > 0) {
        if (number % maxIndex-- == 0) {
            return maxIndex;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Can anyone please direct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just return a *remainder*?

```
public int getIndexForNumber(int number, int maxIndex) {
  return (number - 1) % maxIndex; 
}
```

if *negative* numbers are allowed

```
public int getIndexForNumber(int number, int maxIndex) {
  int x = (number - 1) % maxIndex; 

  if (x < 0)
    x += maxIndex;

  retrun x; 
}
```

Comment: That explains it and it was so straightforward. Excuse me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern in the mapping function, which is that a number n is mapped to (n-1) mod (m+1). Using this, you can write the function as:

```
public int getIndexForNumber(int number, int maxIndex) {
    return (number - 1) % (maxIndex + 1);
}
```